# Javascript get Iframe contents

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm trying to get the content of iframe in a javascript alert but, the alert appears empty

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
</head>

<style>
iframe {height:200px; width:300px; border:1px solid #000}
</style>

<script>
var iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
var iframe_contents = iframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
function newDoc() {
alert (document.getElementById('myFrame').innerHTML) ;
}
</script>

<body>

<iframe src="http://api.adf.ly/api.php?key=c02fe2b360ee4b566a4f1e14d84b279b&uid=3141484&advert_type=banner&domain=adf.ly&url=http://somewebsite.com" id="myFrame">
</iframe><br>

 </br>

 <img src="http://www.giftworksconnect.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/download.png" width="100" onclick="newDoc(); return false;" style=" cursor: pointer;" border="0" id="adflink" />


</body>
</html>
```

any help would be appreciated 
Regards

Edit:

> I'm trying to get the contents of an IFRAME because I'm using Adf.ly
>   Api
>   "http://api.adf.ly/api.php?key=c02fe2b360ee4b566a4f1e14d84b279b&uid=3141484&advert_type=banner&domain=adf.ly&url=http://somewebsite.com"
>   But this api respond with a blank page with the shortend url I want to
>   use the shortened url directly in my site script

Comment: You can't get the contents of iframes cross domain. If you need to do cross domain page scraping, either use JSONP, or use php/asp to scrape the page.

Comment: A better question is *why* are you trying to get the contents of an IFRAME element on a different domain? What exactly are you trying to do (and why?). This would normally constitute "scraping" or creation of a "mash-up", and at the very least you'd normally want to secure permission from the site administrator/owner. If you *can* get that permission, you can use CORS to overcome your cross-domain issues. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: I'm trying to get the contents of an IFRAME because I'm using Adf.ly Api "http://api.adf.ly/api.php?key=c02fe2b360ee4b566a4f1e14d84b279b&uid=3141484&advert_type=banner&domain=adf.ly&url=http://somewebsite.com"
But this api respond with a blank page with the shortend url
I want to use the shortened url directly in my sit script

Answer (score 2):

I guess your main (parent) page is on another domain. In this case your access to the iframe content is forbidden due to cross-domain restrictions.
If you don't have control over the inner page (api.adf.ly/api.php) you can't handle it on with the client-side code on your page.

Answer (score -1):

replace Your below line

```
alert (document.getElementById('myFrame').innerHTML) ;
```

with the below

```
alert(document.getElementById('myFrame').src);
```

Think it will work for You.

Comment: thanks for help, but this gets me the source url not the content